# Leaflet Marker 'dragend' fires 'click'

Tags: javascript, leaflet

When dragging a marker

1. I click the left mouse button and hold it --> this executes **dragstart**
2. I move the marker around and release the mouse button --> it call **dragend** and **click**

When searching through the **leaflet** source I can only find the following hooks for **dragend** in `L.Handler.MarkerDrag`:

```
_onDragEnd: function (e) {
        this._marker
            .fire('moveend')
            .fire('dragend', e);
    }
```

Comment: Which Leaflet version and browser are you using? This *might* be a candidate for a bug report.

Comment: @IvanSanchez Sorry Ivan, I somehow skipped your comment... In Bower we use version `"leaflet": "^0.7.7"` and the chrome version is `50.0.2661.94 m`. It's not working in Firefox either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Switch to Leaflet 1.0.0-rc1. This was fixed in [#3634](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/pull/3634) and is unlikely to be backported to 0.7.x.